# Use Three.Spherical where Z is the axis for the poles

Tags: three.js

Currently THREE.Spherical is disigned to work on referential where the poles (phi) are at the positive and negative y axis.

In architecture field the poles (phi) are at the positive and negative z axis.

How to use THREE.Spherical object in case z is the positive and negative pole axis?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify, is this for the case when you use [`.setFromSpherical()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3.setFromSpherical)?

Comment: It is for both cases : Vector3.setFromSpherical and Spherical.setFromVector3

Comment: Just a suggestion: to use `.applyAxisAngle()` around `THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)` with the angle of `-Math.PI * 0.5` before `.setFromVector3()` and with the angle of `Math.PI * 0.5` after `.setFromSpherical()`.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly!